# Error in consuming XML data Content type 'application/xml;charset=utf-8' not supported spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to process the request with XML Data getting error as

```
RecurlyController.processEvents(java.lang.Object,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]:
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
```

**Controller**

I want XML data of any structure that's why I am using Object in request

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "events", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ModelAndView processEvents(@RequestBody Object recurlyEvent, HttpServletRequest request {
    Response response = recurlyManager.processEvents(recurlyEvent);
    return prepareModelAndView(response);
}
```

**Http request to spring app using postman**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/xml");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<new_subscription_notification>\n  <account>\n    <account_code>1</account_code>\n    <username nil=\"true\">verena</username>\n    <email>verena@example.com</email>\n    <first_name>Verena</first_name>\n    <last_name>Example</last_name>\n    <company_name nil=\"true\">Company, Inc.</company_name>\n  </account>\n  <subscription>\n    <plan>\n      <plan_code>bronze</plan_code>\n      <name>Bronze Plan</name>\n    </plan>\n    <uuid>8047cb4fd5f874b14d713d785436ebd3</uuid>\n    <state>active</state>\n    <quantity type=\"integer\">2</quantity>\n    <total_amount_in_cents type=\"integer\">17000</total_amount_in_cents>\n    <subscription_add_ons type=\"array\">\n      <subscription_add_on>\n        <add_on_code>premium_support</add_on_code>\n        <name>Premium Support</name>\n        <quantity type=\"integer\">1</quantity>\n        <unit_amount_in_cents type=\"integer\">15000</unit_amount_in_cents>\n        <external_sku>pre-123</external_sku>\n        <add_on_type>fixed</add_on_type>\n        <usage_percentage nil=\"true\"></usage_percentage>\n        <measured_unit_id nil=\"true\"></measured_unit_id>\n      </subscription_add_on>\n      <subscription_add_on>\n        <add_on_code>email_blasts</add_on_code>\n        <name>Email Blasts</name>\n        <quantity type=\"integer\">1</quantity>\n        <external_sku>email-123</external_sku>\n        <unit_amount_in_cents type=\"integer\">50</unit_amount_in_cents>\n        <add_on_type>usage</add_on_type>\n        <usage_percentage nil=\"true\"></usage_percentage>\n        <measured_unit_id type=\"integer\">394681687402874853</measured_unit_id>\n      </subscription_add_on>\n      <subscription_add_on>\n        <add_on_code>donations</add_on_code>\n        <name>Donations</name>\n        <quantity type=\"integer\">1</quantity>\n        <unit_amount_in_cents nil=\"true\"></unit_amount_in_cents>\n        <add_on_type>usage</add_on_type>\n        <usage_percentage>0.6</usage_percentage>\n        <measured_unit_id type=\"integer\">394681920153192422</measured_unit_id>\n      </subscription_add_on>\n    </subscription_add_ons>\n    <activated_at type=\"datetime\">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</activated_at>\n    <canceled_at type=\"datetime\"></canceled_at>\n    <expires_at type=\"datetime\"></expires_at>\n    <current_period_started_at type=\"datetime\">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</current_period_started_at>\n    <current_period_ends_at type=\"datetime\">2009-11-29T13:10:38Z</current_period_ends_at>\n    <trial_started_at type=\"datetime\">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</trial_started_at>\n    <trial_ends_at type=\"datetime\">2009-11-29T13:10:38Z</trial_ends_at>\n    <collection_method>automatic</collection_method>\n  </subscription>\n</new_subscription_notification>");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://a346f04e.ngrok.io")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: The URL from the controller doesn't match what you are posting to. Also what are you using to send the information? What is the `request` function?

Comment: @M.Deinum The url is ngrock url with reroutes to my spring app.
I am using post request to accept XML data of any kind of structure

Comment: Check your routes, there must be something being filtered and not passed along to the controller/spring app. Also the code is not using postman it is using OkHttp so not sure why you mention postman? Regarging the POST request you are doing try removing the `addHeader` (as that should already be taken into account when creating the body).

Comment: It worked without consumes

Comment: It should work with it as well. If it doesn't there is something wrong with your input (hence the suggest to remove it in your client call NOT the server side thing.

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for an answer to a similar question.
Removing consumes worked for me.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processEvents(@RequestBody String recurlyEvent, HttpServletRequest request {
    Response response = recurlyManager.processEvents(recurlyEvent);
    return prepareModelAndView(response);
}
```